# A Tricky Partition of Natural Numbers

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, natural-numbers

how you doing guys? I'm a new member of this wonderful forum. I can't thank you enough. I'm Italian, so forgive me for some english mistakes I may do. 
I'm translating a problem, so I hope to do it in the best way. 
Here we are...

Let $\tau$ = $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$
Note that $\tau + 1 = \tau^2$

Let $a_n$=$\lfloor n\tau \rfloor$, $b_n$=$\lfloor n\tau^2\rfloor$ for every natural number

a) Prove that for every number $N>0$ there are $\lfloor\frac{(N+1)}{\tau}\rfloor a_n$ elements and $\lfloor\frac{(N+1)}{\tau^2}\rfloor b_n$ elements which are $\le N$.

b) Prove that:
$N-1<\lfloor{\frac{(N+1)}{\tau}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{(N+1)}{\tau^2}}\rfloor < N+1$

c) Demonstrate that every natural number belongs to $a_n$ or to $b_n$, and that $a_n$ and $b_n$ don't have any common elements.

I have few ideas on how to demonstrate (a) and (b)... I would be very grateful if someone could help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE :). What are your few ideas on (a) and (b) ?

Comment: Note that you can code the floor function in MathJax as \lfloor ... \rfloor: $\lfloor n\tau^2\rfloor$.

Comment: Also, regarding (b), isn't the second inequality $\leq$, `$\leq$`, rather than $<$ ?

Comment: @Surb Well, actually to demonstrate (b) I'd try to use, in some way $\|floor \frac{x}{y}\rfloor$ = $\frac{x - (x mod y)}{y}$

Comment: @rogerl Thank you so much!

Comment: Still, I am puzzled about the statement (b). Since $\tau^2 =\tau+1\geq \tau$, we have $\frac{N+1}{\tau^2}\leq \frac{N+1}{\tau}$. Furthermore, the floor function is increasing, so it seems that the inequality you want to prove is always wrong. Finally, note that for $N=2$, $\lfloor \frac{N+1}{\tau^2}\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{N+1}{\tau}\rfloor$.

Comment: You're right! Even if I checked twice what I wrote I didn't notice the mistake. There's a plus sign actually. I beg you to pardon me! I've corrected it in the main post!

Comment: I would suggest doing a websearch for "Beatty sequences".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, you saved me! I had a quick look this morning while having breakfast. I'm going to analyze it more profoundly when back home.

Comment: Good. When you've had a chance to digest what you find, you could write it up and post it here as an answer.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.